# Custom CSS for mobile font size

Tags: css, iphone, mobile, web, font-size

I am working with a Squarespace template and would like to fix up a few things while viewing my website on a mobile device (iPhone). [www.jobspark.ca](http://jobspark.ca) is my website.

Here is the code I tried and didnt have any luck with.

```
/* ----------Add your custom styles here for Mobile---------- */
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
.desc-wrapper { font-size:24px;  
} 
}
```

I have attached an image to help demonstrate what I am trying to fix. Thanks[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font size is set with

```
.desc-wrapper p
```

so would need to change the size with:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
    .desc-wrapper p {
        font-size: 24px;  
    }

    /* Changes bottom headline */
    .sqs-block-content h1 {
        fonts-size: 18px;
    }
}
```